# Question about Scoped Class injection to controller after POST call in Blazor Web Server using .NET Core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, scope, blazor

Maybe it's a stupid question, but I would like to understand better why my scenario is not working. I created a simple example for explaining what I want to achieve.

Basically I want to inject a class (suppose it is a status) and I want to update a string in this class that should be viewed only by the user that did the action and gets back to the index page. The call to the controller is a simple Post call from a button into a form that change value to the status class. I was expecting to get the value modified in the controller but if I inspect it inside the action method, I see it null (but should not because I set it on the index page).

My example class is like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace BlazorApp_Scoped.Data
{
    public interface ITestClass
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        string Name { get; set; }

        string GetName();
    }

    public class TestClass : ITestClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
        public string Name { get; set; } = "";

        public string GetName() { return Name; }

        public TestClass() 
        {
            Debug.Print("Created");
        }
    }
}
```

After this I set it up the call into `program.cs`:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ITestClass, TestClass>();
```

This is my index

```
@page "/"
@using BlazorApp_Scoped.Data

@inject ITestClass TestClass
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

Nome: @TestClass.GetName()

<br />

<button @onclick="Testb">PagB</button>

@code{

    private void Testb()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/pageb");
    }
}
```

This is my pageb:

```
@page "/pageb"
@using BlazorApp_Scoped.Data

@inject ITestClass TestClass
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<h3>Pageb</h3>

<button @onclick="TestI">Index</button>

<form method="POST" action="api/test">
    <button><span>Controller</span></button>
</form>

@code {

    private void TestI()
    {
        var r = new Random();
        var a = r.Next(10000);
        TestClass.Name = $"TEST{a.ToString()}";
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/");
    }
}
```

So if I just click the button Index I return back to the index and view the right name as expected, but will not work if instead I force the reload of the index, in that case as I understand it's like to make a manual refresh of the page and as connection restarted scoped class gets reset.

If I click on the button for controller (code after explanation) and get redirect into index page I can see that inside the action the value of the testclass is null, and even if I change it the changes get lost, so controller seems to have a different instance of the class created in my application, but why ?

And why when I execute the application I see two time the "Created" message output ?

Controller:

```
using BlazorApp_Scoped.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace BlazorApp_Scoped.Controller
{
    public class HomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost("api/test")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Test([FromServices] ITestClass testclass)
        {
            testclass.Name = "controller";
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            return Redirect("~/");
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad English and bad explanation but I am trying to understand better about Blazor stuff, it's bit complicated for me.

Thank you for any clarification.

Comment: Blazor is designed for real-time web functionality, it maintains a persistent connection to the server and doesn't rely on the request-response model that MVC uses. When you redirect from a controller action, you are effectively initiating a new HTTP request which will result in a new Blazor circuit if it leads to a Blazor component. This means that any scoped services will be re-instantiated. 
As to your debug printed twice , check your _host.cshtml to see if it is render-mode="ServerPrerendered" , change to “Server” to disable prerendering.

Comment: thank you @FengzhiZhou yeah I did guess it too but I found confusing finding so many information about scoped services passed to controllers, this is not a praticable way I guess. Then what I should use if can't singleton class ? Yeah I changed the value to Server and it get called only once, I always forgot to check the ServerPrerender value.

Comment: I would suggest trying builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITestClass, TestClass>(); although that wouldn't be my recommended approach.
For something simple like this ProtectedSessionStorage/ProtectedLocalStorage might better idea. There are some other options here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-8.0&pivots=server

Comment: Thank you @cycaHuH yes I read about it and I was trying to understand better the usage, I read it's not compatible with all the browsers so can be an issue but probably for my need could be good a ProtectedLocalStorage, I will try this path. I'd prefer not to use Singleton in this application if not really needed.

Comment: ah I need to store the value inside a class in c# that inherit from RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider so I guess is not possible to do the ProtectedLocalStorage path @cycaHuH at least from what I understand.

Comment: I am afraid you might be mixing up several questions/issues in one here: DI, State Management and Authentication. What's the real use case that you are trying to solve?

Comment: @cycaHuH well, the real use case is similar to the simple example but I am using RevalidatingServerAuthenticationStateProvider for testing existance of a cookie and sametime testing the max life of a session. Anyway I guess you point me in the right direction to follow, thank you